# create logical volume using python cgi

Tags: python, cgi

I am creating python CGI script that accepts lv size from client and then creates and mount the logical volume using nfs.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type:text/html"
print ""
import cgi,commands,os,socket,time,getpass
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
st=form.getvalue("st")
mount=form.getvalue('mount')
backup=form.getvalue('backup')
ip=os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("192.168.1.100",4444))
a,b=s.recvfrom(100)
print a
s.sendto(mount,b)
if(backup=='Yes'):
    os.system("lvcreate --size "+st+" --thin volume/pooL1")
    os.system("lvcreate -V "+st+" --name "+ip+" --thin volume/pooL1")
    os.system("mkfs.ext4 /dev/volume/"+ip)  
    os.system("mkdir /mnt/"+ip) 
    os.system("mount  /dev/volume/"+ip+"  /mnt/"+ip+"" )
    os.system("lvcreate -s --name snap"+ip+" /dev/volume/"+ip)
    os.system("mkdir /media/snap"+ip)
    os.system("mount /dev/volume/snap"+ip+"  /media/snap"+ip+"")
else:
    os.system("lvcreate --size "+st+" --thin volume/pooL1")
    os.system("lvcreate -V "+st+" --name "+ip+" --thin volume/pooL1")
    os.system("mkfs.ext4 /dev/volume/"+ip)
    os.system("mkdir /mnt/"+ip) 
    os.system("mount /dev/volume/"+ip+" /mnt/"+ip+"/" )
f=open('/etc/fstab','a+')
f.write("/mnt/"+ip+"  /dev/volume/"+ip+"  ext4  defaults 0  0")
f.close()
f=open('/etc/exports','a+')
f.write("/mnt/"+ip+"    "+ip+ "(rw,sync,no_root_squash) \n")
f.close()
os.system("exportfs -a")
s.sendto("now you can use your storage",b)
s.close()
```

st is storage size.
I have given permissions to apache to create logical volume.The problem is lv is not mounting.Also client is getting internal server error even when lv is created at server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write sudo before every command like `os.system('sudo ...')` if you are using rhel version 7.2.

For working sudo user you have to configure `/etc/sudoers` file and adding extra line `#apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` at any line.